# Azure Notification Hub in UWP

Tags: azure, notifications, uwp

I toast notification by Azure Notification hub to UWP Application from ASP.NET website but when I click in notification it opens app and suspend in splash screen then it close immediately , how I fix this  problem ??

I use this tutorial : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I click in notification it opens app and suspend in splash screen then it close immediately

Frequently, [`OnLaunched`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Application#Windows_UI_Xaml_Application_OnLaunched_Windows_ApplicationModel_Activation_LaunchActivatedEventArgs_) is invoked when UWP application is launched and this method is initial created. But if you want to launch the app by toast which [`ActivationKind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.activation.activationkind) is `ToastNotification`, you may need to handle the activated event by overriding the [`OnActivated`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242330) event handle. For example:

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.ToastNotification)
    {
        ProtocolActivatedEventArgs eventArgs = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;
        // TODO: Handle URI activation
        // The received URI is eventArgs.Uri.AbsoluteUri
        var rootFrame = CreateRootFrame();
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
}
```

More details please reference [Handle URI activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation) and the [Notification official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/Notifications/cs/Notifications/App.xaml.cs).